# 'Invalid multibyte sequence in JVM console output: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character' after Java special symbol logging

Tags: java, linux, logging, slf4j

I try to log special symbol '®' with Java slf4j Logger

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

LOG.info("®");
```

And get this error message in console

```
WARN   | wrapper  | main    | 2019/10/10 12:29:09.677 | Invalid multibyte sequence in JVM console output: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
```

My locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

What the reason of the problem?

```
echo ®
```

This command works

Comment: try to use "\u24C7"

Comment: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/24c7/index.htm

Comment: No, doesn't work, the same error

Comment: If `LOG.info("\u24C7");` still delivers an invalid multibyte sequence, then there must be a wrong conversion from java Unicode, to UTF-8/... bytes, and wrongly again to UTF-8 bytes. Maybe in combination with a FileAppender and a ConsoleAppender. Inspect the logging configuration.